# Rails 4 - triple nested parameters not showing in parameters hash on edit form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, nested

I am having a triple nesting issue. The parent and its children were created on a different form, this is an edit form that allows the user to add additional (triple nested) items, but when the form is submitted the attributes do not appear in the params hash. Why might this be?

[here is my code](https://gist.github.com/EminenceHC/f82439550801bd2aef39)

Answer (score 0):

Deeply nested routes become [cumbersome](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

I would suggest nesting one model with another then nest your third model with the other.

Example:

```
resources :books do
 resources :chapters, except: [:index]
end

resources :chapters do
 resources :table_of_contents, except: [:index]
end
```

With the above code, I have Chapters nested with Books and TableOfContents nested with Chapters